# the deep meaning of ArrayBufferLike's typescript definition

Tags: typescript

What's the meaning of the typescript definition for `ArrayBufferLike`?

```
interface ArrayBufferTypes {
    ArrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer;
}
type ArrayBufferLike = ArrayBufferTypes[keyof ArrayBufferTypes];
```

According to my understanding, `keyof ArrayBufferTypes` is a union type of `ArrayBufferTypes`'s property. so,

```
type Properties = keyof ArrayBufferTypes; // 'ArrayBuffer'
```

thereby `ArrayBufferLike` is obviously equal to `ArrayBuffer`.

But there must be some differences, otherwise the `ArrayBufferLike` would be defined as `type ArrayBufferLike = ArrayBuffer`.

Anyone can help to explain this definition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is to allow `ArrayBufferTypes` to be extended using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

This single-member interface is defined in [lib.es5.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ee25cdecbca49b2b5a290ecd65224f425b1d6a9c/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1437)

```
interface ArrayBufferTypes {
    ArrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer;
}
```

But the interface with the same name, but having another member, is defined in
[es2017.sharedmemory.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9c71eaf59040ae75343da8cdff01344020f5bba2/src/lib/es2017.sharedmemory.d.ts#L28)

```
interface ArrayBufferTypes {
    SharedArrayBuffer: SharedArrayBuffer;
}
```

When both type declarations are included in the program, declarations will be merged and the resulting union type

```
type ArrayBufferLike = ArrayBufferTypes[keyof ArrayBufferTypes];
```

will have two members now: `ArrayBuffer` and [`SharedArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer).

Comment: wow, thanks. This makes sense. I haven't notice there is another definition.

Comment: @artem Sorry, but it's still not clear to me: Declaration merging should already work by defining these two interface declarations, why the extra type `ArrayBufferLike` is necessary?

Comment: It does not seem to be necessary. I was able to pass `SharedArrayBuffer` into a function expecting `ArrayBuffer`.