# Initializer type ArrayBufferLike is not assignable to variable type ArrayBuffer

Tags: typescript

Typescript newbie here.

I am trying to create an ArrayBuffer from an array for testing purposes. I opted to create UInt8Array first to convert it to ArrayBuffer by calling `.buffer`. This however gives me an ArrayBufferLike. Typescript complains then that it cannot be assigned to ArrayBuffer.

`Initializer type ArrayBufferLike is not assignable to variable type ArrayBuffer`

How to resolve this kind of assignment error?

My code snippet.

`const mockEncrypted: ArrayBuffer = new Uint8Array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]).buffer;`

Comment: There are at least two types of `ArrayBufferLike` things floating around... there's [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) and [`SharedArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer).  Is there a reason you can't just use the `ArrayBufferLike` type?

Comment: (see also the related question ["The deep meaning of ArrayBufferLike's typescript definition"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416170/the-deep-meaning-of-arraybufferlikes-typescript-definition))

Comment: I guess that would be one way to solve it.

Comment: It is just weird that PromiseLike it compatible with Promise but not same case with ArrayBuffer